# How can I compile the Rust no_mangle function calls C functions in macOS

Tags: c, macos, rust, clang

I wrote the below Rust functions that can be called from C that calls the C function.

```
#![crate_type = "cdylib"]
#[no_mangle]
pub fn foo() {
    unsafe {
        bar();
    };
}

extern "C" {
    pub fn bar();
}
```

I compiled the code in macOS, then…

```
$ rustc src/lib.rs
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" …
  = note: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
            "_bar", referenced from:
                _foo in lib.lib.3a1fbbbh-cgu.0.rcgu.o
          ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
          

error: aborting due to previous error
```

This happens in macOS but not in Linux.

How can I compile the code in macOS?

My clang version is `clang-1103.0.32.62` .

---

EDIT:

I want to use the above Rust function in C like this:

```c
extern void foo();

int main() {
  foo();
}

void bar() {
}
```

Therefore, I think I cannot specify a #[link(...)] to `bar` .

(That is, I want to write a plugin in Rust for a C program.)

Comment: Seems like macOS's LLVM expects functions to begin with an underscore. I do not have a Mac to test on right now, but [this issue might help](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/35052)

Comment: Aren't you missing the `#[link(...)]` to the c `.so` that has `bar()` in it? See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63394094/rust-linker-seeks-a-lib-rather-than-a-dll/63394405)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't know if I understand linker behavior, but I made some changes to the question.